# Meteor reactive maps don't work as should

Tags: google-maps, meteor, google-maps-api-3

I am using two brilliant packages named `dburles:google-maps` and `mdg:geolocation`. What I nee is to add a marker and change map's zoom automatically when I get user's geolocation data (after he allows it to share).

#### Inside `Template.onCreated` I have the following code:

```
Template.dealersMap.onCreated(function() {
    Tracker.autorun(() => {
       this.latLng = new ReactiveVar(Geolocation.latLng());
    })
});
```

#### Then in `onRendered` I do the following:

```
Template.dealersMap.onRendered(function() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    GoogleMaps.ready('exampleMap', (map) => {
      let marker;

      if(!this.latLng.get())
        console.log('Didn\'t get the location..');

      if(!marker) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(
              this.latLng.get().lat, 
              this.latLng.get().lng
          ),
          map: map.instance
        });
      } else {
        marker.setPosition(this.latLng.get());
      }
      map.instance.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
      map.instance.setZoom(11);
    }, () => {
      console.log('deny');
    });
  })
});
```

As result after user allows me to get his geodata nothing happens. **But** if user changes at least one step map zoom — everything works.

The question is — how to make this code work without letting user change map zoom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just removed `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` and now everything works fine. Here is the successful code:

```
Template.dealersMap.onCreated(function() {
  this.latLng = new ReactiveVar();
  Tracker.autorun(() => {
    this.latLng.set(Geolocation.latLng());
  })
});


Template.dealersMap.onRendered(function() {

  this.autorun(() => {
    GoogleMaps.ready('exampleMap', (map) => {
      console.log('map is ready');


      let marker;

      if(!this.latLng.get()) {
        console.log('Didn\'t get the location..');
      } else {
        if(!marker) {
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(
              this.latLng.get()
              .lat,
              this.latLng.get()
              .lng
            ),
            map: map.instance
          });
        } else {
          marker.setPosition(this.latLng.get());
        }
      }
      map.instance.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
      map.instance.setZoom(11);
    })
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Tracker` to rerun the once the dta is changed like, once uses share his/her location, the marker is triggered. Here is the example code:

```
Template.dealersMap.onRendered(function() {
var self=this;
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
GoogleMaps.ready('exampleMap', (map) => {
  self.autorun(function() {   //tracker function
  let marker;

  if(!this.latLng.get())
    console.log('Didn\'t get the location..');

  if(!marker) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(
          this.latLng.get().lat, 
          this.latLng.get().lng
      ),
      map: map.instance
    });
  } else {
    marker.setPosition(this.latLng.get());
  }
  map.instance.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  map.instance.setZoom(11);
}, () => {
  console.log('deny');
}
});
})
});
```

Comment: Hello Ankit! Thanks for your answer. I have already tried tracker, and it gives no effect. I have changed now the code in app, which is available by temp link. As you see the behavior is the same.

Comment: I see. I did a similar thing with a project but was not using the user's current location. Can you try putting the  `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` block inside the `google.maps.ready` and inside the tracker function.

Comment: Done. Now `navigator.geolocation` is executing only when I come from another browser tab. looks like magic )